Page not found, Keycloak SSO
Keycloak, client details:
client ID: phpclient1 (OpenID Connect)
root URL: http://localhost:8081
home URL: http://localhost:8081
Admin URL: http://localhost:8081


capability console, 
Client authentication: On
Authorization: On

Localhost (docker)
My directory structrue:
├── docker-compose.yml
├── php-client1
│   ├── 000-default.conf
│   ├── apache2.conf
│   ├── callback.php
│   ├── composer.json
│   ├── composer.lock
│   ├── docker-entrypoint.sh
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── index.php
│   └── vendor
├── php-client2
│   ├── 000-default.conf
│   ├── apache2.conf
│   ├── composer.json
│   ├── composer.lock
│   ├── docker-entrypoint.sh
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── index.php
│   └── vendor
└── README.md

I browse to: http://localhost:8081/
Here is my PHP code for http://localhost:8081/index.php:
index.php
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider;

session_start();

$provider = new GenericProvider([
    'clientId'                => 'phpclient1',
    'clientSecret'            => '****************************',
    'redirectUri'             => 'http://localhost:8081/callback.php',
    'urlAuthorize'            => 'http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/auth',
    'urlAccessToken'          => 'http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token',
    'urlResourceOwnerDetails' => 'http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo',
]);

if (!isset($_GET['code'])) {
    // If we don't have an authorization code then get one
    $authorizationUrl = $provider->getAuthorizationUrl();
    $_SESSION['oauth2state'] = $provider->getState();
    header('Location: ' . $authorizationUrl);
    exit;

// Check given state against previously stored one to mitigate CSRF attack
} elseif (empty($_GET['state']) || ($_GET['state'] !== $_SESSION['oauth2state'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['oauth2state']);
    exit('Invalid state');

} else {
    // Try to get an access token (using the authorization code grant)
    try {
        $accessToken = $provider->getAccessToken('authorization_code', [
            'code' => $_GET['code']
        ]);

        // We have an access token, which we may use in authenticated
        // requests against the service provider's API.
        echo 'Access Token: ' . $accessToken->getToken();
        echo '<br>';
        echo 'Refresh Token: ' . $accessToken->getRefreshToken();
        echo '<br>';
        echo 'Expired in: ' . $accessToken->getExpires();
        echo '<br>';
        echo 'Already expired? ' . ($accessToken->hasExpired() ? 'expired' : 'not expired');
        echo '<br>';

        // Using the access token, we may look up details about the
        // resource owner.
        $resourceOwner = $provider->getResourceOwner($accessToken);

        var_export($resourceOwner->toArray());

    } catch (\League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Exception\IdentityProviderException $e) {
        // Failed to get the access token or user details.
        exit($e->getMessage());
    }
}

http://localhost:8081/callback.php
callback.php
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider;

session_start();

$provider = new GenericProvider([
    'clientId'                => 'phpclient1',
    'clientSecret'            => '****************************',
    'redirectUri'             => 'http://localhost:8081/callback.php', // Ensure this matches your Keycloak client configuration
    'urlAuthorize'            => 'http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/auth',
    'urlAccessToken'          => 'http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token',
    'urlResourceOwnerDetails' => 'http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo',
]);

try {
    // Try to get an access token (using the authorization code grant)
    $accessToken = $provider->getAccessToken('authorization_code', [
        'code' => $_GET['code']
    ]);

    // We have an access token, which we may use in authenticated requests against the service provider's API.
    echo 'Access Token: ' . $accessToken->getToken();
    echo '<br>';
    echo 'Refresh Token: ' . $accessToken->getRefreshToken();
    echo '<br>';
    echo 'Expired in: ' . $accessToken->getExpires();
    echo '<br>';
    echo 'Already expired? ' . ($accessToken->hasExpired() ? 'expired' : 'not expired');
    echo '<br>';

    // Using the access token, we may look up details about the resource owner.
    $resourceOwner = $provider->getResourceOwner($accessToken);
    var_export($resourceOwner->toArray());

} catch (\League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Exception\IdentityProviderException $e) {
    // Failed to get the access token or user details.
    exit($e->getMessage());
}

?>

I'm then redirected to authorize with my Keycloak client http://localhost:8080:
http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/auth?state=f3b34a35407633b40c1f5d55c9bdc3e9&response_type=code&approval_prompt=auto&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8081%2Fcallback.php&client_id=phpclient1
Only, the page returns Page not found?

I tail the keycloak logs looking for errors:
docker logs -f sso-php-docker-keycloak-1
nothing displayed there for my most recent request.
Ensure both services are on the docker network:
docker network inspect sso-php-docker_sso-network
[

    {
        "Name": "sso-php-docker_sso-network",
        "Id": "24374221e5137536979bca420f0973b3baefa92f92b10bd1ba03337abe11e069",
        "Created": "2024-08-06T13:56:25.440837682+01:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.19.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.19.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "29bdff1f5846f54e44cd395c4c7a30c832237b2ed39ab67bfb38b6a33bf765dd": {
                "Name": "sso-php-docker-php-client2-1",
                "EndpointID": "ddfa9f8b84f2a17e05cc4f079616d545974d1500b39c0729adc8829ef594ad3b",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:04",
                "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.4/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "b7eec6f4bc35e465c5e1ca37bc419a543fea0f4eb80ebade8bd5993ddbc67f34": {
                "Name": "sso-php-docker-php-client1-1",
                "EndpointID": "c3c3bed5e3f99707fe18edace6c0d0f8a257fa547f9bca8cf0af7da6a9f0b13e",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "f364de72a5f987f9a08dfd01f4bc34ed0024e9e245b8141de4a636c43b6a2b74": {
                "Name": "sso-php-docker-keycloak-1",
                "EndpointID": "0dfb9d9bb5a2f186df59e1c3412a91d0a2fd1d4b5ff6614afcc64dd32d8b9e75",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "sso-network",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "sso-php-docker",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "2.28.0"
        }
    }
]


Check if we can reach the Keycloak container from withing php-client1
docker exec -it sso-php-docker-php-client1-1 /bin/sh
curl -v http://keycloak:8080
*   Trying 172.19.0.2:8080...
* Connected to keycloak (172.19.0.2) port 8080 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: keycloak:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.88.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Location: http://keycloak:8080/admin/
< Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< content-length: 0
< 
* Connection #0 to host keycloak left intact


gives success.

What version of Keycloak are you using here? What does your docker-compose.yml look like?
